# iPhone - UITableViewController - Setting section header in portrait and landscape

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sectionheader

I'm having UITableView controller which uses custom section header view. When my device is portrait, its showing perfect. And when my device is landscape its perfect again. But when orientation changed during app runtime, its not updating my section view. What's the problem?

Using following code, I'm adding a label, and two buttons to a view and returning that view in "viewForHeaderInSection". During debugging I found that the method is getting called, but the section header view is not updating.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 80;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary* dict = [threadsArray objectAtIndex:section];

    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.2];

    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 15, self.view.frame.size.width - 98, 21)];
    newLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    newLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    newLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:newLabel];

    UIButton* addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    addButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 88, 11, 29, 29);
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",addButton.frame.origin.x,addButton.frame.origin.y, addButton.frame.size.width,addButton.frame.size.height);
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addThreadResponseClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [headerView addSubview:addButton];

    UIButton* expandCollapseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [expandCollapseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Expand.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    expandCollapseButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 48, 11, 29, 29);
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",expandCollapseButton.frame.origin.x,expandCollapseButton.frame.origin.y, expandCollapseButton.frame.size.width,expandCollapseButton.frame.size.height);
    [expandCollapseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandCollapseHeader:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [headerView addSubview:expandCollapseButton];

    addButton.tag = expandCollapseButton.tag = section;
    return [headerView autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the views [autoresizing masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) appropriately: eg for headerView;

```
[headerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

and for addButton and expandCollapseButton set the AutoresizingMask to:

```
UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleLeftMargin
```

Comment: If you see my code, when ever orientation changes, I'm creating the new headerView. Even I tried setting the auto resizing masks. It didn't help me.

Comment: instead of referring to view's frames use bounds instead, generally bounds are used when adding subviews, as the frame doesn't necessarily switch width and height when the UI is rotated as you'd expect (its a bit haphazard and something I hope Apple fix)

Comment: set auto resizing mask fix my problem. Thank you