# reduce width of section

Tags: iphone

how to reduce the width of section in UITableView ?

Answer (score 1):

The width of the section is the width of the tableView. What you can do, if is change the apparence of the secion and make it transparent on the right and it will appear shorter than the tableView.

You can customise a section with these two methods:

```
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops up to me is using the following code in viewwillappear:

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = theTableView.frame;  
tableViewFrame.size.width = newWidth;  
theTableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
```

Perhaps with a [tableview reloaddata] after it.

Let me know if it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about section header maybe this will help you

[iPhone - UITableViewController - Setting section header in portrait and landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133628/iphone-uitableviewcontroller-setting-section-header-in-portrait-and-landscape)